# How to store changes to a page in tornado.no/cms?

Tags: groovy

In a controller for a page in tornado-cms, I do the following:

```
def res = Service.tornado.articles([ articleCategoryPath: "boker/ny"]);
Service.tornado.loadFullArticles(res);
res.sort { a,b -> 
  b.props.year <=> a.props.year 
}
tornado.small_articles = res;
```

Or, shorter:

```
tornado.small_articles = Service.tornado.articles([ 
  articleCategoryPath: "boker/ny", 
  full: true ])
.sort { a, b -> b.props.year <=> a.props.year };
```

This fills the content box `small_articles` with the all the articles from a specific folder "boker/ny" reversely sorted by the article prop `year`.

It works fine, but is it possible to save the changes made to the content box `tornado.small_articles` so that the resulting list of articles is also visible from the GUI? Something like `Service.tornado.saveChangesToPageContentBox(page, content_box_nr, tornado.small_articles);`?

Comment: I just learned from the documentation that I can do the entire operation in one step by adding the `full:true` to the search query. `tornado.small_articles = Service.tornado.articles([ articleCategoryPath: "boker/ny", full: true ]).sort { a, b ->
  b.props.year <=> a.props.year 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by removing the articles currently bound to the small_articles box like this:

```
Integer containerId = <id-of-small-articles-container>;

Service.tornado.getPageBindings(page.id).each { binding ->
    if (binding.containerId == containerId)
        Service.tornado.deletePageBinding(binding);
}
```

Then add new bindings for the articles you have collected:

```
tornado.small_articles.each {
    Service.tornado.addPageBinding(new ArticlePageContainer(page.id, it.id, containerId));
}
```

You should not do this on every request to the given page, but rather update the list when the content changes or by some other, less frequent criteria.